# What are the consquences of unmounting during a network request (memory leak warning)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If a react component is unmounted during an asynchronous effect that has subsequent state updates, we are met with a warning that says it indicates a memory leak.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('checking value...');
useEffect(() => {
    fetchValue().then(() => {
     setValue("done!"); // ⚠️ what if the component is no longer mounted ?
     // we got console warning of memory leak
   });
}, []);
```

Warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

There are numerous questions on what to do to remove this warning, **but why should I attempt to remove it?** I think the most common scenario this happens is after network requests, which I assume after completion would leave the component free for garbage collection (correct me if I'm wrong). Since the state updates are no-op, is there any reason to do something about the warning except for the sole purpose of not having to see it?

I understand that there are scenarios where this is important, like unsubscribing to event, but it isn't very common in my experience.

The reason for asking is that handling the unmount state in a large application is a hassle, especially if you haven't build it with this in mind from the start.

Question: Are there any end-user consequences of ignoring the memory leak warning from scenarios like shown above?

Bonus question: Is it possible to disable the warning somehow?

Comment: `let isMounted = true; fetchValue().then(() => {if (isMounted) setValue("done!"); return () => { isMounted = false; }` "handling the unmount state in a large application is a hassle" it isn't hard to check if component is mounted or not...

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal That actually was slightly easier than i've seen elsewhere, where it is usually suggested to use `useRef` for the mount state. But either way, it is one more state to keep track of on top of loading, data and error states. Most probably it would go in a common "useFetch"-like hook, but it is very far from always we use that pattern.

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114, IMHO they say it is ok for API requests.

Comment: @giorgimoniava Thank you! that is exactly what I wanted to read :), and I think it answers my question: OK to ignore for most cases. Not possible to disable. If you'd like you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114) is correct, that warning was added to protect against such cases:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handleChange() {
     setState(store.getState())
  }
  store.subscribe(handleChange)
}, [])
```

When the `store` could *indefinitely* hold a reference to the the component (even after it unmounts), thus causing memory leaks.

But in other situations like making a API call once when nothing references the component *indefinitely*, it should be fine.